# Sql query to find rows with different values for some columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below data in a table

```
    Employee id       Status       email          partition 
            A          P           a@mail.com      1
            A          P           a@mail.com      2 

            D          T           d@mail.com      1
            D          T           d@mail.com      2

            G           P          g@mail.com      1
            G           T          g@mail.com      2
```

We expect all three columns for one employee should be same for partition 1 and 2. If there is any employee for which either of the three columns are different between partition 1 and 2, those two records should be returned.

For the above data, query should return two records for Employee G.
Could anyone please help with the query?

Comment: Show your desired output.

Comment: @NareshK You could use analytic **LAG()**.

Comment: You need this query because you have denormalized screwed up data, admit it ;)

Answer (score 2):

This code will return you all rows, where there is no partition=2 for the employee (single record) or some fields are different in two rows.

```
select t1.*, t2.* 
from tbl t1
    left join tbl t2 
    on t2.Employee_id = t1.Employee_id 
    AND t2.partition >  t1.partition
where t2.Employee_id is null
OR t1.Status != t2.Status 
or t1.email != t2.email
```

Comment: For each employee, there should be two records with partition=1 and partition=2 respectively.

Comment: Just set outside `Select * from tbl t3,  (SELECT t1.Employee_id as Employee_id1, t2.Employee_id as Employee_id2 <..> ) as t2 where t3.Employee_id = t2.Employee_id1 or t3.Employee_id = t2.Employee_id2`

Comment: @NareshK you say "there should be two records" but your need for this query is precisely because you have data *which isn't how it should be* .   Once you start down the denormalization route it becomes impossible to predict how the data will become corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the expected result:

```
select * from tablename where employee_id in (
     select t1.employee_id 
     from tablename t1 
       left outer join tablename t2 on t1.employee_id = t2.t2.employee_id and t1.status = t2.status and t1.email=t2.email and t1.partition=1 and t2.partition=2 
     where t2.employeeid is null )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the structure of your table insted of writing complex queries,

The simple solution is to have 2 Tables

1. Table Employee (EmployeeID, Status, Email) with Employee Id as Primary Key
2. Table Partition (EID Foreign key, Partition number).

This will assure you of better desing and non-redundant tables.

Comment: EmailAddr is typically a horrible idea for pk

Comment: @DrewPierce I admit that given lot of fake accounts, but this would be quiet good when it is a organization's internal database.

Comment: Not thinking fake at all from my thinking but rather normalized data and 3rd normal form. I wouldn't even have email address in employee table it is foolish. Google 3rd normal form

Comment: yes @DrewPierce, When 3NF is considered, Eliminating either EID or Email will suffice. :-)

Comment: The eid ought to be in employee. Then other tables hang under it using eid

Comment: I like your thinking just not pk's as email

Comment: I Agree, Thank you @DrewPierce, I was not considering this point till now, I will change my DB structure now. Great Observation

Comment: It comes at a cost but one's data isn't a mess

Answer (score 0):

You could use analytic **LAG()** function.

**Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE t
  (
    Employee_id VARCHAR2(1),
    Status      VARCHAR2(1),
    email       VARCHAR2(10),
    partition   INT
  );
​
INSERT ALL 
    INTO t (Employee_id, Status, email, partition)
         VALUES ('A', 'P', 'a@mail.com', 1)
    INTO t (Employee_id, Status, email, partition)
         VALUES ('A', 'P', 'a@mail.com', 2)
    INTO t (Employee_id, Status, email, partition)
         VALUES ('D', 'T', 'd@mail.com', 1)
    INTO t (Employee_id, Status, email, partition)
         VALUES ('D', 'T', 'd@mail.com', 2)
    INTO t (Employee_id, Status, email, partition)
         VALUES ('G', 'P', 'g@mail.com', 1)
    INTO t (Employee_id, Status, email, partition)
         VALUES ('G', 'T', 'g@mail.com', 2)
SELECT * FROM dual;
COMMIT;
```

**Query**

```
SQL> WITH t1 AS(
  2  SELECT t.*, LAG(status) OVER(PARTITION BY employee_id, email ORDER BY status) rn FROM t
  3  ),
  4  t2 AS(
  5  SELECT Employee_id, Status, email, PARTITION FROM t1
  6  WHERE
  7  status <> rn
  8  )
  9  SELECT t.Employee_id,
 10    t.Status,
 11    t.email,
 12    t.partition
 13  FROM t,
 14    t2
 15  WHERE t.Employee_id = t2.Employee_id
 16  ORDER BY t.partition;

EMPLOYEE_ID STATUS EMAIL       PARTITION
----------- ------ ---------- ----------
G           P      g@mail.com          1
G           T      g@mail.com          2

SQL>
```

Comment: This fits the specific sample data but won't find rows which match on STATUS but have a different EMAIL

Comment: @APC OP stated *We expect all three columns for one employee should be same for partition 1 and 2* Which means EMAIL would be same.

Comment: Well "all three columns" also means the STATUS should be the same.  Why test for one column failing the rule and not the other?

Comment: @APC, Ah! I see. Reading OP's question again and I fimd that any of the three columns other than partition column could be different and not just status column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Select 
    t1.* 
from 
    table t1, table t2
where 
    t1.partition < t2.partition 
and t1.employee_id = t2.employee_id
and (t1.status != t2.status or t1.email !=t2.email)

Union all

Select 
    t2.* 
from 
    table t1, table t2
where 
    t1.partition < t2.partition 
and t1.employee_id = t2.employee_id
and (t1.status != t2.status or t1.email !=t2.email)
```

Comment: Sorry I missed to add temp table in query, I have updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite universal and hits data only once:

```
select employee_id, status, email, partition 
  from ( 
    select test.*, 
        count(1) over (partition by employee_id, status, email) cnt1,
        count(1) over (partition by employee_id) cnt2
      from test )
  where cnt1 <> cnt2
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8fa0d9/1)</sup>

This query will also deal with situation, when there are 3 or more rows for one person, not all matching.
And if one employee has only one row - and you want to show it as anomaly - add `or cnt2 = 1` in last line.